# How to solve producer-consumer problem using atomic_compare_exchange_weak?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing, synchronization

I am implementing the 'producer-consumer problem' in C, which solves the synchronization problem of redundant production, redundant consumption, and consuming unproduced items when multi-threading.

```
bool expected = false; 
while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&lock, &expected, true))
    expected = false;
```

In order to prevent duplicate access of the process, the *atomic_compare_exchange_weak* was used.

I know that the *atomic_compare_exchange_weak* can block access of another process when one process enters critical section. However, duplicate access of the process continues to occur. How can I solve this problem? Below is my producer and consumer code.

**producer code**

```
void *producer(void *arg) {
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    int item;
    
    while(alive) {

        while(counter >= BUFSIZE);
        
        expected_p = false;
        while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&lock_p, &expected_p, true))
            expected_p = false;
        
        item = next_item++;
        
        buffer[in] = item;
        in = (in + 1) % BUFSIZE;
        counter++;  
            
        if (task_log[item][0] == -1) {
            task_log[item][0] = i;
            produced++;
            lock_p = false;
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            continue;
        } 
        printf("<P%d,%d>", i, item); 
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}
```

**consumer code**

```
void *consumer(void *arg)
{
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    int item;

    while (alive) {

        while (counter <= 0);

        expected_c = false;
        while (!atomic_compare_exchange_weak(&lock_c, &expected_c, true)) 
            expected_c = false;
        
        item = buffer[out];
        out = (out + 1) % BUFSIZE;    
        counter--; 
        
        if (task_log[item][0] == -1) {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            continue;
        }
        else if (task_log[item][1] == -1) {
            task_log[item][1] = i;
            consumed++;
            lock_c = false; 
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            continue;
        }
        printf("<C%d,%d>\n", i, item);   
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

**global value**

```
int buffer[BUFSIZE];
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
int counter = 0;
int next_item = 0;

bool expected_p = false;
bool expected_c = false;
atomic_bool lock_p = false;
atomic_bool lock_c = false;
```

Comment: Lockless programming is incredibly difficult to get right. Whatever benefit you think you are getting from trying to do this lockless is negated by the `while (counter <= 0);` spin loops that you have.

Comment: @selbie Thank you for answer. It looks good to get rid of the while loop before atomic_compare_exchange_weak. Then how do I prevent situations where an item is consumed before it is produced, and an item is produced when the buffer is full?

Comment: I wrote up an answer below on the proper way to use a mutex and conditional variable together to get improved thread safety, better maintainability, and better performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a pthread_cond and pthread_mutex instead of trying to do something crazy with atomics.  The code below may have more overhead using a real lock that an atomic primitive, but it's far safer and more maintainable. Further, the condition variable in place of your spin loops will increase performance of both threads dramatically - overcoming the overhead of using a real lock.

Declare a mutex and a pair of condition variables:

```
pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_can_write, cand_can_read;
```

Then start both threads and modify as follows:

```
void *producer(void *arg) {

    int i = *(int *)arg;
    int item;
    
    while(alive) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);  // TAKE THE LOCK

        // wait for counter to go below BUFSIZE
        while (counter >= BUFSIZE) {
            // atomically release lock and wait for consumer thread to signal
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_can_write, &mut);

           // when pthread_cond_wait returns, this thread has reacquired the lock
        }

        // DO YOUR PRODUCE LOGIC HERE        

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut); // EXIT THE LOCK

        // signal to consumer that it can read
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond_can_read);
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL); 
}

void *consumer(void *arg)
{
    int i = *(int *)arg;
    int item;

    while (alive) {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);   // TAKE THE LOCK

        // Wait for the counter to go above 0
        while (counter <= 0) {
            // atomically release lock and wait for producer thread to signal
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_can_read, &mut);

            // when pthread_cond_wait returns, this thread has reacquired the lock
        }

        // DO YOUR CONSUME LOGIC HERE

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);  // EXIT THE LOCK

        // signal to producer that it can write again
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond_write);

    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@seiblie provides a much better answer to your problem; but as to why what you posted doesn't work.....

You are using two different spinlocks (lock_c, lock_p); yet *counter* is modified via both paths, thus is unpredictable.

Also your spin on *counter* is wrong.   There is a dependency between buffer[out] and counter, yet your program permits them to be updated out of order.  That is, *counter* might tell you that there is something to read at *buffer[out]*, but it is entirely possible that *counter* has been updated before *buffer[out]*; so you will find stale data there.